# How to POST a XML body with "UTF-16" encoding in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, character-encoding

I have a problem when I want to post a XML body with the encoding "UTF-16" in a .NET Core API.

It function when I post the body like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
</resources>
```

But with this body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<resources>
</resources>
```

it throws this exception:

> System.Xml.XmlException:The encoding in the declaration 'UTF-16' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.

The configuration in my startup.cs is like that:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddDbContext<CFContext>();

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false
    };

    services.AddMvc(options => {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter(settings));
        //options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlOFormatter());
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

Someone knows a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem that it refuses to parse an XML that promises to be in UTF-16 but in fact is in UTF-8? Did you simply change `encoding="UTF-8"` for `encoding="UTF-16"` without actually re-encoding the content in UTF-16?

Comment: Im new in working with XML, so I think that was just to change the header....

Comment: What if you set [`XmlWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-5.0)?  Also, what version of asp.net-core are you using?

Comment: You might also try removing `Encoding.Unicode` from [`XmlSerializerOutputFormatter.SupportedEncodings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.textoutputformatter.supportedencodings?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Formatters_TextOutputFormatter_SupportedEncodings) after constructing it.

Comment: [Content Negotiation in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation#selecting-a-character-encoding) (which is admittedly obsolete) states, *After a formatter is selected, the content negotiator chooses the best character encoding by looking at the SupportedEncodings property on the formatter, and matching it against the Accept-Charset header in the request (if any).*  What is the Accept-Charset header in the request?

Comment: @MarlonDanielZaldivar It is not about being new to XML. Any piece of text (which XML is) may be in [one encoding or another](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @dbc I try to set XmlWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 and I get the same exception, im using .Net Core 3.1